# Using a modal to display information

Tags: forms, user-expectation, modal-windows

I am working on a dashboard to display menus. Throughout the site, we use modals to display important or separate information that prompts user action.

Now, there is possible design for a modal to display just information that was entered by the user: a feedback form that they filled out through a form modal.

Is is appropriate to use a modal here to display the entered information? My concerns are consistency of modal use on the one hand. On the other, since the user entered that information via the same modal, is it consistent to display it in the same flow?

Comment: Do you have a flow diagram to visually explain your issue? As you know, a picture is worth a 1000 words ;)

Comment: I agree, a picture would help understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to define what consistency means and how it is applied in UX design. You can define a specific rule for using modal windows (e.g. accepting user input), or you can define a specific rule for accepting input (e.g. use a modal window). But you will find that in one instance you might have different needs for accepting user input (e.g. long or short input) which may not be appropriate to use a modal window for, such as a long form that would require scrolling in a window that can be displayed fully on a page.

It also becomes more complex when you have many different functions and features that form various types of user workflows. I think the key here is to try and map out all the different scenarios and make sure that you can apply any rules consistently (or adapt them when you need to). This way you'll be able to avoid problems with consistency.

Answer (score 0):

further to what Michael has said about consistency, I think it's important to analyse what the modal window is asking and ask whether it really is so important that you must break the flow of the page and force the user into interacting with another interface.

Is it appropriate to force feedback? It sounds dramatic, but that's what a modal window is. If not I would consider another channel to obtain feedback.

Generally, when modal windows open on website asking for feedback, I can't close them fast enough.